# Entity Framework check if child belongs to parrent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Is there a short way to find out with Entity Framework if an entity belongs to a parent?

There are some tables for example: Manager-> Project->Document.

Suppose this chain is longer and there are lot's of different chains. Can I write sort of a universal method that would check if the last child in the chain belongs to parent (first table in the chain)?

In this example - check if Document belongs to Manager.  May be this needs a recursive function?

Answer (score 1):

Try [this solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SCKpbt) in assumption that we have such models and `LazyLoading` is turned on:

```
public class Manager
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }     
    public virtual ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }        
    public virtual Manager Manager { get; set; }
    public int? ManagerId { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    public int? ProjectId { get; set; }
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
public static TParent FindParentOf<TParent, TChild>(TChild child)
    where TParent : class
    where TChild : class
{
    return FindParentOfRecursive(child, typeof(TParent)) as TParent;
}

private static object FindParentOfRecursive(object child, Type parentType)
{
    var IEnumType = typeof(IEnumerable);
    var childType = child.GetType();
    var strType = typeof(string);

    foreach (var prop in childType.GetProperties()
        .Where(x => x.PropertyType.IsClass && x.PropertyType != strType 
                    && !IEnumType.IsAssignableFrom(x.PropertyType)))
    {
        //calling to database via LazyLoading with query like: 
        //select top(1) * from dbo.Parents where Id = child.ParentId
        var parentVal = prop.GetValue(child);

        if (prop.PropertyType == parentType)
            return parentVal;
        else if(parentVal != null)
        {
            var result = FindParentOfRecursive(parentVal, parentType);
            if (result != null)
                return result;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var manager = FindParentOf<Manager, Document>(doc);
if(manager?.Id == lookingForManagerId)
    Console.WriteLine("Belongs");
```